# Reuse atomic uint in DrawElementsIndirect as voxel count

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm currently trying to implement sparse voxel octrees according to GPU insightss: https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-SparseVoxelization.pdf

In this book they describe how to voxelize a 3d mesh and how to create an octree as a compact represenation of the voxelized mesh. One intermediate step is to voxelize the mesh and to store the voxels in a preallocated array, where the target location in the array of any voxel is defined by an atomic counter (which I implemented)

Now I'm not sure if I can bind the first Gluint of DrawElementsIndirectCommand (which is used in the DrawElementsIndirect call) first as a GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER and then rebind it to the target GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER because I want to draw the Voxels for debugging purposes now.

I assume I can rebind it, but I'm not supposed to call glBufferData again?

Comment: Buffers can be rebound to any target at any time. glBufferData is not directly related to the binding target but allocates memory. If you call it, then the previous content gets deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I didn't have the time to veryify this so far, but you seem to be quite confident about this

Comment: My first tests were not successful so I ended up copying the buffer. Now I can use the buffer for glDrawArraysIndirect once but somehow the memory gets invalid after that (I only call glBindBuffer and bind the buffer to GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, but after SwapBuffers the memory is invalid). 

Is this expected behaviour?

Before SwapBuffers the memory is valid and the output looks correct in RenderDoc, the only commands followed by SwapBuffers are glUseProgram, glBindBuffer und glDrawArraysIndirect. Renderdoc shows the buffers invalid directly after SwapBuffers

Comment: Please prepare a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the described behaviour and ask a new question. We can then have a look at it.